# Uniform and pointwise convergence of $n\ln(1 + \frac{2^x}{n})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Check $f_n(x) := n\ln(1 + \frac{2^x}{n})\ x \in (0, 1)$ for pointwise and uniform convergence.

I am able to show that $\ f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $2^x$ (just apply exponentiation). However, it is hard to tell something about uniform convergence.

For example, if I take $2^x$ as $f(x)$ and want to show that $f_n(x)$ uniformly converges to $f(x)$, I have to find or at least estimate $\sup \limits_{x \in(0, 1)} |n\ln(1 + \frac{2^x}{n}) - 2^x|$, and this is the point where I got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $[0,1]$ is compact, and you have pointwise convergence already and $f_n(x)\nearrow$ at $n$ fixed, and $2^x$ continuous, then second Dini's theorem applies here.

[wikipedia: Deuxième théorème de Dini](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8mes_de_Dini#Deuxi.C3.A8me_th.C3.A9or.C3.A8me_de_Dini)

*[I don't know why, but there is only the first Dini's theorem on English language wiki].*

You should not be afraid that the $f_n$ are only defined only $(0,1)$ since they are trivially extendable continuously on $[0,1]$.

Note that you can arrive at this result manually since

$n\ln\left(1+\dfrac {2^x}n\right)-2^x=n\left(\dfrac{2^x}n-\dfrac{4^x}{2n^2}+o(\dfrac{4^x}{2n^2})\right)-2^x=-\dfrac{4^x}{2n}+o(\dfrac{4^x}{2n})$

And since $|4^x|\le|4^1|\le 4$ is bounded, all this is $\bigg|n\ln\left(1+\dfrac {2^x}n\right)-2^x\bigg|<\dfrac kn$ for some $k$ when $n\ge n_0\gg 1$.

And you get your uniform convergence.

---

EDIT:

The Taylor expansion I think is straightforward, so I guess your concern is why

$\bigg|-\dfrac{4^x}{2n}+o(\dfrac{4^x}{2n})\bigg|<\dfrac kn$ ?

First thing is that we work for $x\in[0,1]$ so $1\le 4^x\le 4$, this is essential for uniform convergence because this is here that we get rid of the dependency in $x$.

So we get $0\le\dfrac{4^x}{2n}\le \dfrac 4{2n}\le \dfrac 2n$

Secondly by definition of $o$, for any $\varepsilon$ and $n$ big enough, or let say $\forall n\ge n_0\gg 1$ we have

$\bigg|o(\dfrac{4^x}{2n})\bigg|\le\bigg|o(\dfrac{2}{n})\bigg|\le \dfrac{2\varepsilon}{n}\quad$ and the choice of $n_0$ is independant of $x$.

Finally $\bigg|f_n(x)-2^x\bigg|\le \dfrac{2+\varepsilon}{n}\le \dfrac 3n$ for $\varepsilon\le 1$ for instance.

And we have an upper bound that depends only on $n$ and goes to $0$ for an $n_0$ that does not depend on $x$, this is the definition of uniform convergence.

Comment: Ah...suddenly after all that time I realized that I don't understand your solution via Taylor expansion. It would be nice if you can clarify some of my doubts: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484103/clarifying-the-solution

Comment: I edited, does it clarify your doubts? If not, please tell what bothers you.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response. It does clarify some of the questions. However, I still have one. >The Taylor expansion I think is straightforward. This might be not the case with me. So, the Taylor expansion is true for all points that lie in $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $0$, since you expand it at $0$? If so, then the original function is equivalent to $-\dfrac{4^x}{2n}+o(\dfrac{4^x}{2n})$ only for $x$ from $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $0$ and then this approximation is not true for whole interval $(0, 1)$, even if you are saying that $4^x < 4$, if $x \in (0, 1)$.

Comment: I think I have some problem with understanding Taylor expansion and how does it works and for what $x$ the approximation is true. I do have a feeling that problem might be that this approximation is true for all interval $(0, 1)$ and I'm untruthfully saying that it is only true for $x \to 0$.

Comment: Ah...yeah the expansion of $\log (1 + t)$ is true $\forall -1 < t \leq 1$. And finally, since $0 < \frac{2^x}{n} < 1$, this expansion is true for all $x \in (0, 1)$, right?

Comment: Ok, I see your concern. Let say the Taylor expansion is true for $u\in(-\delta,\delta)$ only, for instance, a very small neighbourhood of zero. Here $u=\frac{2^x}n$ so $|u|<\frac 2n$ can be rendered a small as desired independently of $x$. It all comes back to choose an appropriate $n_0$. You can notice that the neighbourhood $(0,\delta)$ in which the Taylor expansion is valid has nothing to do with $(0,1)$ the domain for $x$. All that interests us is that it is **bounded** so $2^x$ is merely a *constant*.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your efforts!